# Cleanest way to invert the binary value of an char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, binary

Lets say I have a char array of len = 2.

```
char* array = malloc(2);
memset(array, 0, 2);
```

This is 2 bytes = 0000000000000000. How could I turn this into 11111111111111111?

I can do it with a for loop and a pointer, but I don't think this is the cleanest way of doing it.

Comment: Can copy the array into a `uint16_t`, then use the `~` operator on it, then copy it back into the array. Watch out from Endian-ness issues though. Actually, since you copy back, that's not even an issue.

Comment: I ended up doing memset(array, 255, size); is that bad?

Comment: `memset(array, ~0, 2)` would be nicer IMO... Thought you wanted to invert **any** value, not just zeros...

Comment: To invert a general `char` array of arbitrary length and unknown content, the best approach is probably to loop over all the bytes and invert each one individually via the `~` operator.  There's no need to copy bytes around to different objects, and doing so would be inefficient.  It's also unsafe to alias a pointer of non-character (and non-void) type to your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that your length, `2`, is just in your example, and you want to have something work no matter the length of the char array. You still need a loop, but you can invert the binary values of up to 64 bits at once (on a 64 bit CPU, disregarding SIMD capabilities). If you are REALLY looking for THE BEST performance, you need to look into SIMD.

You can check the remaining length of the array (values you have not inverted) in every iteration of the loop, and invert 64, 32, 16 or 8 bits at once, the biggest that fits.

Comment: In a general sense, yes, but the question is about how to do this *in C*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, but this very much seems like homework and someone already mentioned the `~` operator, I don't intend to write the complete function here. I explained what to do.

Comment: If you don't think it appropriate to write a *bona fide* answer to the question, then don't.  But don't write a non-responsive answer, either.  What you've written here is appropriate for a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
uint16_t x;
memcpy(&x, arr, sizeof x);
x = ~x;
memcpy(arr, &x, sizeof x);
```

Comment: This is very un-clean and ineffective. Why not just `uint16_t *x = (uint16_t*)&arr;`

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset Because that violates the language's aliasing rules and is undefined behaviour. Anyway, compilers may optimise away the `memcpy`s into what you 'really' meant. Writing legal code that is guaranteed to work is better than writing succinct code and hoping for the best.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset: Very bad!!! You cannot rely on `arr` being aligned to a 16-bit address. This will yield unexpected results on some platforms.

Comment: @goodvibration, actually, yes, you *can* rely on the memory returned by `malloc()` to be properly aligned, but Hans's suggestion nevertheless does potentially violate the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Maybe with `malloc`, but not in general (i.e., if you allocate the array statically).